# How to correctly include usb accessory shared library

Tags: android

I was having some difficulties using the usb accessory with android api 10 (2.3.3).

I switched to Google API instead of Android for the build target, and that got rid of all the compilation errors, but when I try to run it, this error results.

I am trying to set up a simple test to control the arduino light from a button on the android.

Thanks!

[image: screenshot of usb.accessory failing]